# Make a sharepoint webpart available only for specific users

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am developing a Sharepoint (2010) web part and I want to make it available only for specif users or groups pragmatically.

Because I am a total beginner in Sharepoint development, I found some pieces of code around the Internets, but they give no clue about how or where to use that code from withing the web part itself.

I need a simple how-to method for achieving this.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it strictly have to be applied - you could use audience targeting to show it to members of specific groups

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-a-web-part-to-a-specific-audience-HA010168840.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Like Shaneo said, Audience targeting might be the answer. Although if you are new to SharePoint, Audience might be a new concept to you.